# Jenkins windows slaves not launching

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

Am Using Jenkins, where so many windows machine i have integrated, but at the same all the windows machine got disconnected could not able to launch slave in windows machine, tried all possibilities like

1. slave.jar version upgrade
2. Java_home_path changes
   but my doubt is with port, am getting error while launching that slave as follows
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElPTY.png)

So how to connect windows slave , Hope it may be the issue with port connection.TCP port 443 used but getting error. Please suggest good  idea.

Comment: The problem is most likely that the port for the slave agents is blocked at the Jenkins master end, on the security page you can change the port that the slaves use, it can be random or a specific port, make sure it's the port is not blocked on the master. I had this issue with a red hat master.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the port you are using (in this case, TCP port 443) is not being used by another application or service on the Windows machine.

You can use the following command in the Command Prompt to check for open ports:

```
netstat -an | find "443"
```

Comment: add the command in blocks